# How to save bot data using Bot framework and azure

Tags: c#, sql, database, azure, botframework

I'm using Bot Framework to build my bot and language C#. I have deploy my code in Azure. I want to save all the bot conversation in a database.

I was reading a document : https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/05/Saving-Bot-Actions-On-Azure-Sql-Server/ from microsoft.

But in the step that i have to add a project of  Class Library (.NET Framework) i found in my project only  Class Library (.NET Core). I'm using Visual Studio 2015 .  I made all the steps that this documents propose but i not able to link database created in azure with my project, and make it work.

I try to create a local database...i publish my project , and then my bot cannot start conversations.

Do you have any idea how to save all the conversations of my bot in SQL server database

Comment: Did you use the template to create the bot?  The blog post you referenced assumes that this template was used to create the bot: http://aka.ms/bf-bc-vstemplate

Answer (score 0):

You just have to download and install Microsoft .Net Framework SDK. You can try .Net Framework 4.5.2 from [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637)

Comment: i download it and install but i don't have any change in my project i mean i don't see Class Library (.NET Framework) . Do you have some instruction how to save my bot data ?

Comment: What section is chosen on left side of New project window? Make sure that you've selected the Templates/Visual C# section

Comment: your bot builder version may not be compatible with the class library .net framework version.